# PHP SOAPClient Request Issue

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am trying to call this web service http:// 115. 186. 182.11/csws/Service.asmx?op=SendSMS  with following PHP code but it gives me exception  Error mate in Script: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Will highly appreciate your help on this.

```
try     {       

$client = new SoapClient("http://115.186.182.11/csws/Service.asmx?wsdl"); 

$method = 'SendSMS';

$params = array(
new SoapParam('xxxxx', 'Src_nbr'),
new SoapParam('xxxxxx', 'Password'),
new SoapParam('xxxxx', 'Dst_nbr'),
new SoapParam('xxxxx', 'Mask'),
new SoapParam('Message is test message', 'Message')
);

$result = $client->__call($method,$params);

}
catch(SoapFault $e){
echo "Error mate in Script: " . $e->getMessage();
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";

$xmlobj = simplexml_load_string($result);
print_r($xmlobj);
```

FOllowing is the specification...

```
POST /csws/Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 115.186.182.11
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/SendBulkSMS"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SendBulkSMS xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Src_nbr>string</Src_nbr>
      <Password>string</Password>
      <Dst_nbr>xmlxml</Dst_nbr>
      <Mask>string</Mask>
      <Message>string</Message>
    </SendBulkSMS>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SendBulkSMSResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <SendBulkSMSResult>
        <string>string</string>
        <string>string</string>
      </SendBulkSMSResult>
    </SendBulkSMSResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below method finally and it is working perfect in production.

```
$fields = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <SendSMS xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Src_nbr>xxxx</Src_nbr>
      <Password>123</Password>
      <Dst_nbr>xxxxxxxxxx</Dst_nbr>
      <Mask>xxxk</Mask>
      <Message>Aoa, This is Test. From xxx.</Message>
      <TransactionID>11122276</TransactionID>     
    </SendSMS>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>'; 
echo $fields;


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$fields");
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);
```

In production the [SMS API](http://www.innovativetxt.com/) was using this code and code was exected more than 20 time per seconds and performance is good as-well.